# Icon for app using Phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to apply an icon to my application i have made in PhoneGap locally. I have searched as much as possible and i have only found ways to apply a icon for the application on PhoneGap build however i am building the application Locally in Eclipse.

Can someone please help me or share a link to useful resource!

I'm using PhoneGap 1.5.0 and i just updated Eclipse to the latest version.

My application is coded using HTML 5. Any help will be useful and appreciated. Thanks

~~~Issue Resolved~~~
Dan's answer below helped and now I have a icon in the launcher menu :D

Comment: You mean the application icon for the launcher menu?

Comment: if u replace the icon.png in the res folder, it'll pickit up

Comment: @dan yes  i did mean in the launcher menu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You provide your Icon in the drawable Resource Folder in .png format and set it in the AndroidManifest.xml, Application Tab.

> Icon:   @drawable/name_of_your_icon

directly in the graphical editor, no code required.