# How to add custom app icon on Android in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Do you know how to add a custom .png icon on Android in Phonegap? I changed the AndroidManifest.xml "android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" to a custom name but it's not working. In addition, my icons are all in the www/res/drawable folders with the correct sizes each png should be. I have no idea what the deal is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [PhoneGap Builder](https://build.phonegap.com/) for easily describing the app icon in the [config.xml](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml/).

But if you don't want to use the builder this threads perhaps can help you:

[App icon for Android in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230810/app-icon-for-android-in-phonegap)

[Icon for app using Phonegap for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699352/icon-for-app-using-phonegap-for-android)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if it didn't save as a correct png when i finished it in photoshop but it works now. Thanks for the threads!

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you're doing a **local build** the `config.xml` is ignored and the icon used is the one at `platforms/android/res/drawable`

Comment: What do you mean by local build? I'm using phonegap and by typing `phonegap build android` my config.xml icons are completely ignored, it just adds the typical phonegap icon.